# How do I find out which package version will `apt-get install <package>` install?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

How do I find out which software version will `apt-get install <package>` install?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt-get install -s package`

Answer (score 3):

This is very usefull command if you have more sources for the same package:

```
apt-cache policy package_name
```